# Setting DateTimePicker Value Error

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

I know (from references) that the value of `DateTimePicker` can be set like the following:

```
DateTimePicker exampleDtPicker = new DateTimePicker();
exampleDtPicker.Value = new DateTime(2010, 10, 6);
```

However, this doesn't change the value displayed on the form, yet displays the current local date. 
Does different properties from default of `exampleDtPicker` affects setting value of `DateTimePicker`? These are the properties of `exampleDtPicker` :

```
DateTimePicker exampleDtPicker = new DateTimePicker() {
    Checked = false,
    Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
    ShowCheckBox = true;
}
```

What is causing the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: I'm very confused. "this doesn't change the value displayed on the form, yet displays the current local date" Where does it display the current local date if not the form? Is `exampleDtPicker` part of your form? Are you making these changes in the designer.cs file? Etc., etc.

Comment: @itsme86 Well that's my confusion too.. If I do `Console.WriteLine(exampleDtPicker.Value)`, the value on console is well-printed. Seems like I "must" change the value on designer.cs file? Because I changed the value in the constructor of `MainForm`.

Comment: You want to avoid re-instantiating controls that you've created using the designer. Try your second line of code where you set its `Value` property without creating a new control (the first line of code). It seems like you're creating a separate locally-scoped `DateTimePicker` object and aren't manipulating the one created by the designer at all.

Comment: @itsme86 The first line of the example code was written to just indicate that  the type of `exampleDtPicker` is `DateTimePicker`. In real code, I use designer to create the control.

Comment: ** PLEASE DON'T EDIT MY POST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DateTimePicker` has the property `Checked` set to `false`. With such setup, if you are setting its `ShowCheckBox` to `false` somewhere else (and probably even if you don't do it)... chances are it will never update itself no matter what `Value` you pass in. From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.checked(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the Value property has been
>   set with a valid date/time value and the displayed value is able to be
>   updated.

and:

> This property is used to obtain the state of the check box that is
>   displayed if the P:System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker.ShowCheckBox
>   property value is true. If the
>   P:System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker.Checked property value is true,
>   the T:System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker control displays the
>   properly formatted P:System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker.Value
>   property value; otherwise, the control displays the last valid
>   date/time value assigned to the
>   P:System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker.Value property or the current
>   date and time (P:System.DateTime.Now) if no value has ever been
>   assigned.

Comment: Oh I got it. I solved the problem when I changed `Checked` property to `false`. Thanks a lot! I've never guessed that this might be the problem.

Comment: One more question - I still want to set `Checked` property to `false`, so I set it to `true` first, then changed the `Value` of `DateTimePicker`, and then changed `Checked` property to `true`, but still it doesn't display the correct date. How should I solve the problem?

Comment: Ok let's do things step by step. Don't touch the Checked property. Leave it to true and try to set a value. What happens?

Comment: It works fine when I set value with Checked property true.

Comment: Ok so your previous question is not clear. You set it to true, then you change the value and then you set it to TRUE again?!

Comment: Oh I made a mistake - I changed the `Checked` property to false after changing the value.

Comment: I have the sensation that what you are attempting to do is tricky... I need to build up a test